# vbam-wx has unmet dependencies, so can't complete any apt commands

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

Whenever I try to install almost anything onto my Xubuntu OS, such as VirtualBox, I always get an error that looks something like this.

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
state information... Done You might want to run 'apt-get -f install'
to correct these. The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
vbam-wx :  Depends: libsfml-network2 (>= 2.1) but it is not installable
           Depends: libsfml-system2 (>= 2.1) but it is not installable
           Depends: libwxbase3.0-0 (>= 3.0.2) but it is not installable
           Depends: libwxgtk3.0-0 (>= 3.0.2) but it is not installable
```

Can someone tell me what any of this means and how to fix it?

Comment: According to https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libdevel/libwxgtk3.0-dev the package is available for 'Trusty' (ie. 14.04 LTS) in the `universe` repository. Do you have universe enabled?   (*i considered providing a command to enable it, but i think its better you check its enabled/disabled and change yourself.  via gui or term*)

Answer (score 1):

The system tells you that there are some unmet dependencies in your packages tree and offers to correct this by command **`apt-get -f install`**.

It's better to do that at first, and at second (if first didn't help) uninstall package **`vbam-wx`**, because it wasn't installed properly and most likely it won't work.